may I need to know when type is passed into a generic or inferred by TS?
Goal is to provide typing for simple array generator(it's a learning exercise to wrap my head around inferring, so let's ignore low practical value)
function generateArr(count, init) {
    if (typeof init === 'function') {
        return new Array(count).fill(undefined).map((_value, index) => init(index))
    } else {
        return new Array(count).fill(init)
    }
}

ideally it should allow both inferring and providing type explicitly. So this was my version which does not work in all the cases:
function generateArr<T extends (index: number) => any>(count: number, init: T): ReturnType<T>[];
function generateArr<T>(count: number, init: T): T[];
function generateArr(count: number, init: unknown): unknown[] {
    if (typeof init === 'function') {
        return new Array(count).fill(undefined).map((_value, index) => init(index))
    } else {
        return new Array(count).fill(init)
    }
}

const a1 = generateArr(2, 'a')
//    ^? string[]

const a2 = generateArr<'a' | 's'>(2, 'a')
//    ^? ('a' | 's')[]

const a3 = generateArr(2, () => 's' as 'a' | 's')
//    ^? ('a' | 's')[]

const a4 = generateArr(2, {a :4})
//    ^? { a: number }[]

const a5 = generateArr<'a' | 's'>(2, () => 's')
// ERROR Argument of type '() => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "s"'.(2345)

TS rightfully goes to a second overload and requires me to have init of the same type 'a' | 's'.
I was finally able to reach this with NoInfer<>, but I don't like how complex it became
function generateArr<T extends (index: number) => any>(count: number, init: T): ReturnType<T>[];
function generateArr<T>(count: number, init: NoInfer<(index: number) => T>): T[]
function generateArr<T>(count: number, init: T): T[];
function generateArr(count: number, init: unknown): unknown[] {
    if (typeof init === 'function') {
        return new Array(count).fill(undefined).map((_value, index) => init(index))
    } else {
        return new Array(count).fill(init)
    }
}

Are there better ways? Should I try to distinguish whether T is manually provided and write separate overloads?

Trying to distinguish between inferred and explicitly specified type args is a seriously off-label use of TypeScript. The example you're giving doesn't lend itself to such a solution either; I'd just use a union as shown in this playground link. There are ways to do what you're trying to do, but could you please [edit] to show a [mre] that motivates it? I don't mind writing up an answer but ideally the problem should motivate the solution.

@jcalz, your solution with unions absolutely works. I did not know that in such a case Typescript will ever pick (index: number) => T  instead of init: T part. So I thought I have to let Typescript knowing "pick the callback if it ever passed". Here my intention on detecting inference comes from. I think I came to wrong conclusions what I need to do from wrong understanding how TS detects/chooses T. Let me update the title to be less straight and please file an answer with union, which you can start with "you should not try detecting type inference" :)

updated a post to be a wider question "does detection make sense?" instead of "how to detect auto-inference". Next time, I'll be more careful with wording.

For the particular example here, I'd say you only need a single generic call signature where the init parameter has a union of the possible types:
// call signature
function generateArr<T>(count: number, init: ((i: number) => T) | T): T[];

// implementation
function generateArr(count: number, init: unknown): unknown[] {
    if (typeof init === 'function') {
        return new Array(count).fill(undefined).map((_value, index) => init(index))
    } else {
        return new Array(count).fill(init)
    }
}

And you'll see that TypeScript will automatically prefer infer T the way you wanted it to, even when init is a function:
const a1 = generateArr(2, 'a')
//    ^? const a1: string[]    
const a2 = generateArr<'a' | 's'>(2, 'a')
//    ^? const a2: ("a" | "s")[]    
const a3 = generateArr(2, () => 's' as 'a' | 's')
//    ^? const a3: ("a" | "s")[]    
const a4 = generateArr(2, { a: 4 })
//    ^? const a4: { a: number; }[]    
const a5 = generateArr<'a' | 's'>(2, () => 's')
//    ^? const a5: ("a" | "s")[]
const a6 = generateArr(2, (a) => ({ a }));
//    ^? const a6: { a: number; }[]

That covers all the cases you care about in the question.

It is somewhat possible that you might find yourself wanting to distinguish type argument inference from explicit type argument specification, and there are methods to sort of get this to happen, although it's an off-label use of TypeScript and there are usually ways around any such method. The easiest way is to add an extra dummy type parameter for the call signatures you'd like to force to be inferred:
function generateArr<T extends (index: number) => any, U extends never>(
    count: number, init: T): ReturnType<T>[];
function generateArr<T, U extends never>(count: number, init: T): T[];

function generateArr<T>(count: number, init: ((index: number) => T) | T): T[]

Now when someone manually specifies the type argument for T, there's only one valid call signature that works. On the other hand, when you don't manually specify the type argument, one of the earlier call signatures will be selected. If someone actually does specify two type arguments, then they can break it, but presumably you'd document the function so as not to encourage such behavior.
But since this isn't really needed for generateArr(), I wouldn't reach for this solution in this case. Future readers might have a more motivating use case.
Playground link to code

awesome, thank you jcalz. Is there a specific logic behind selection for candidates on T among union members? like, const a6 = generateArr(2, (a) => ({ a })); not returning ((number) => {a: number})[] because of init: .... | T? I checked and ordering in union does not matter

There's a logic, but it's not well-documented. The old spec says that when inferring to T | F<T>  the F<T> will be tried first before the T (that's why you get the function first). But the actual inference algorithm has evolved since then.

may you please add this part to the answer? this is an important insight even if it refers to older versions of TS.
